# Soundpool Frequently Showing Significant Latency And Issuing "deep-buffer-playback" Message

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am testing Soundpool on a Moto-E running 5.1. It often starts with excellent latency - but then the audio begins hanging for a hundred milliseconds or more with the following message:

> 06-26 15:03:49.213 3865-9536/? E/DEBUG MESSAGE: Play Note BEFORE
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.331 299-876/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) kvpairs: routing=8
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.331 299-876/? V/msm8916_platform: platform_get_output_snd_device: enter: output devices(0x8)
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.331 299-876/? V/msm8916_platform: platform_get_output_snd_device: exit: snd_device(headphones)
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.331 299-876/? D/audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_set_anc_parameters: anc_enabled:0
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.331 299-876/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_set_parameters: str_params NULL
>
> 06-26 15:03:49.334 3865-9536/? E/DEBUG MESSAGE: Play Note AFTER

The DEBUG messages are mine. The others are system generated. Notice I am losing over 100ms. I checked my sample rate and it is good. It also doesn't happen for every note. May I ask if anyone is familiar with this type of error?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. Your phone enters in sleep mode: you can stream music with long buffers (via the `deep_buffer`) and between each buffer refill, your CPU enter to sleep.

It is a normal behavior to spare the battery.

A quick solution is to comment the section containing the flags `AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_DEEP_BUFFER` in the `$system/etc/audio_policy.conf`:

```
deep_buffer {
  sampling_rates 8000|11025|12000|16000|22050|24000|32000|44100|48000
  channel_masks AUDIO_CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO
  formats AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_16_BIT
  devices AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_EARPIECE|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ALL_SCO|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_AUX_DIGITAL|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_PROXY|AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_LINE
  flags AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_DEEP_BUFFER
}
```

Or, to use a soft like this one https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-universal-deepbuffer-remover-t3577067